# Issue with shopping cart rule. Please help

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, free-shipping

I am having an issue with a shopping cart price rule. I am basically giving customers free shipping for certain products and paid shipping for other products. The rule is working fine when you have a single product in the cart, but when you add a free shipping product with a paid shipping product, shipping is showing as free instead of being charged the shipping for the other product. Attached is a screenshot of my settings. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shopping cart price rules like these can be a bit confusing.  You have the top part set up properly.

However, at the bottom, you need to restrict which products you want the free shipping to apply to.

Right now, you have this option: 
"Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)"

... blank...

... so it's applying this rule to all items in the cart.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome that worked great! My only concern is that it is adding a bit of extra shipping for any extra item. Not full shipping but just extra dollars. Do you know why? Thank you so much!